# Is there anyway to minify selection by common hierarchy in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, minify

In short, I would like to turn this:

```
#WRITE-USER input[type=text],
#WRITE-USER input[type=password],
#WRITE-USER input[type=email],
#WRITE-USER textarea,
#WRITE-USER select {
     /* common properties */
}
```

In something like this:

```
#WRITE-USER {
     input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], textarea, select {
          /* common properties */
     }
}
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to use LESS or SASS.

Comment: ..and even if you did it woudl still OUTPUT the same CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in plain css but you can use the following css implementation that do exactly that:

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/

**Less** css is great since it works in the browser itself, you can even use variables in your css and change them on the go with javascript on a button click.

**Sass** css is better if you want to compile it to css afterwards and want to compile css serverside in nodejs as example.

Personally I prefer less css since I can easily combine it with javascript to dynamically change whole colorschemes with a single color variable. Less css can also be minified like normal css, since that's just removing spaces etc but the site will always need to fetch the less.js resource when it's not cached and less css does not work without javascript enabled.

You could even do this:

```
#WRITE-USER {
    /* write-user styles */
    input {
        /* input styles */
        &[type=text],
        &[type=password],
        &[type=email], {
            //specific input type style, yes we can use single line comments now
        }
    }
    textarea {
        /* textarea style */
    }
    select {
       /* select style */
    }
}
```

Most interesting and usefull feature would be mixins and variables, no more code repeating :D

Comment: Thank you, friend! Unfortunately the risk that javascript is disabled forces me to use plain CSS. However, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Not by using plain CSS. You need to use a precompiler like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to achieve this, which allows for [such syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules), and results in plain-old non-minified CSS when compiled.

Comment: Thank you, friend! Unfortunately the risk that javascript is disabled forces me to use plain CSS. However, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @HiagoTakaki SASS is compiled to plain CSS by the developer before reaching the user's browser and thus it requires no JavaScript.

Comment: @Skrebom Thanks! I did not analyze it very carefully. Now the feature seems much more usual.